# Apache Spark or Spark-Cassandra-Connector doesnt look like it is reading multiple partitions in parallel?

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql, spark-cassandra-connector

Apache Spark or Spark-Cassandra-Connector doesnt look like it is reading multiple partitions in parallel.

Here is my code using spark-shell

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StringType
spark.sql("""CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW hello USING org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra OPTIONS (table "hello", keyspace "db", cluster "Test Cluster", pushdown "true")""")
val df = spark.sql("SELECT test from hello")
val df2 = df.select(df("test").cast(StringType).as("test"))
val rdd = df2.rdd.map { case Row(j: String) => j }
val df4 = spark.read.json(rdd) // This line takes forever
```

I have about 700 million rows each row is about 1KB and this line

`val df4 = spark.read.json(rdd)` takes forever as I get the following output.

Stage 1:==========>                                         (4866 + 24) / 25256]

so at this rate it will probably take roughly 3hrs.

I measured the network throughput rate of spark worker nodes using iftop and it is about 75MB/s (Megabytes per second) which is pretty good but I am not sure if it is reading partitions in parallel. Any ideas on how to make it faster?

Here is my DAG.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: How many executors/cores your application occupies? What is the `spark.defaultParallelism` value?

Comment: I have following values in spark-env.sh 

export SPARK_WORKER_CORES=12
export SPARK_MASTER_OPTS="-Dspark.deploy.defaultCores=4"

Comment: And I can try any values you may suggest real quick. spark.defaultParallelism ( I dont think I set any values for that and as a matter of fact I dont even know how to set on top of my mind). so whatever is the default and I am using standalone cluster

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot for the Spark job? Can you include the DAG of the Spark job in your question?

Comment: Looks like there is only two tasks running in parallel. How many Cassandra nodes do you have? Your settings suggest you should have 12 cores per executor, meaning 24 tasks should run in parallel. Therefore I think you should look into the ReadConf of the connector.

Comment: Sorry I have 24 running. that was a typo . edited the question. I have 8 node cassandra and two Spark workers

Comment: @JacekLaskowski perhaps 3hrs given my setup is reasonable ?! Anyways, What benefits do I get if colocate nodes? we deploy on AWS and AWS has EBS (network backed SSD storage) which has a throughput of 92.5 MB/s for m4.xlarge and Network throughput is 1Gbps=125 MB/s. so given that EBS is slower than Network why would one colocate nodes? and what is a standard practice?

Comment: Colocating nodes makes sense when running on dedicated hardware where network is the bottleneck. For your setup you're right that it will most likely not be very beneficial to do so. You still might want to consider using more than two workers to increase write output of your result. Currently you're retrieving data from 8 nodes and funnel it through two nodes, so these two might be I/O bound now.